# Branching Submodel in Keras and Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Let's say I have a model, which has 2 inputs. The first input is a number, and the second input is another number, which in reality is a class.

This model is split into 2 submodels. First sub-model works on the input, and the second sub-model works on the output of the first sub-model.

The value of the first input will very greatly by the output of the second. Thus, I wish to be able to have multiple candidates of the first sub-model, and dynamically select which one to use at each step, both during training and inference, based on the value (class) of the second input.

I did not manage to achieve this. I tried using the tf.cond, the tf.switch_case and several other things, but I never managed. When I asked chat GPT it said I should be using PyTorch for this. Is there really no way to do this ?

Comment: TensorFlow indeed provides mechanisms for conditionally selecting different sub-models or branches based on input values, similar to what you are attempting to achieve. While PyTorch benefits from dynamic computational graphs that make such conditional operations more straightforward, TensorFlow also supports dynamic computations using control flow operations like tf.cond, tf.switch_case, or even manual Python logic with if statements.